# Laravel and Lighthouse, it always read the dafault schema

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, laravel-lighthouse

I'm following the tutorial on Lighthouse website for the master version (4.1).

https://lighthouse-php.com/4.1/getting-started/tutorial.html#installation

I make a fresh intallation of Laravel 5.8, then I execute the commands written in the tutorial (beside `npm install`)

`composer require nuwave/lighthouse mll-lab/laravel-graphql-playground`

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Nuwave\Lighthouse\LighthouseServiceProvider"`

`php artisan vendor:publish --provider="MLL\GraphQLPlayground\GraphQLPlaygroundServiceProvider"`

after that a `/graphql/schema.graphql` file is created (under the project root, not under the `routes` folder as happened with the previous versions).

Now I populate the DB with some data and then I copy/paste the schema from the tutorial page to the published schema, I start the server, then I access playground which shows the correct url where to send the requests `http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql`.

Clicking on the `Schema` tab I always see the default schema and not the one published in `/graphql/schema.graphql`, and of course the queries for the resources different from the users fails with an error like `Cannot query field "posts" on type "Query".`. I've already tried restarting the server and refreshing the Playground page.

Into the `config/lighthouse.php` file the schema is registered to the path `base_path('graphql/schema.graphql')` which looks correct.

Why Playground always shows the default schema and not the published and edited one?

I'm using PHP 7.2.14 and Lighthouse requires PHP>7.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I thought the problem is related to the caching. I tried to add `LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_ENABLE=false` to the laravel .env file and restart the server then refresh the playground page. I recheck the schema and it is updated.

I hope it's useful.

Comment: Not all heroes wear capes. Thank you.

Comment: for me it worked in conjunction with `php artisan lighthouse:clear-cache`