# Lighthouse PHP - cannot view schema definition and docs in playground

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, schema, laravel-lighthouse

for some reason I am not able to see the current schema definition/docs for the typedefs and resolvers I made on the playground itself.

Some checks were the following:

- `php artisan lighthouse:validate-schema` - returns a handful of typos/errors and was fixed.
- `php artisan lighthouse:print-schema` - after fixing the errors above was able to print the schema on the terminal
- `LIGHTHOUSE_CACHE_ENABLE=false` - [Laravel and Lighthouse, it always read the dafault schema](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57582140/laravel-and-lighthouse-it-always-read-the-dafault-schema)

After doing the steps above I expected to now see the schema on the playground but with no chance. Anyone facing the same issue, or anyone have any idea how to resolve the problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clear lighthouse config cache through this command

```
php artisan lighthouse:clear-cache
```

It might be help.